# How to position a UWP top level window with a fixed width to appears on the side of the display (like a TaskBar)

Tags: uwp, location, window, coordinates, display

I can't find how to change the initial coordinate of a top level window (the Main Window) to appears on the side of the display (to look like a docked toolbar)?

Please not that I do not want to have a Top Level Window that fill the whole screen with a Docking container, either if the the window background is transparent.

I want to only cover the side of the screen (similar to the Windows TaskBar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid there is no way to make window close to side of the screen. Currently, uwp doesn’t provide such api to support this feature requirement. If you do want this feature, please submit your feature requirement to Windows Feedback Hub app.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I think you are right. I search and found nothing. I will wait a little longer to make sure there is really no alternative. WinUI is coming and I hope will solve this. I think most resources are dedicated to WinUI and my chances to see my request answered are probably extremely low.

Comment: It seems that you are right... My bounty does not bring any better answer ;-) !!! Thank you very much!!!